# How to display the complete address with curl in searching?

Tags: curl

I need to display the complete address with [curl](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm), when it find results with '301' status code.

This is my variable.

```
search=$(curl -s --head -w %{http_code} https://launchpad.net/~[a-z]/+archive/pipelight -o /dev/null | sed 's#404##g') 

echo $search
301
```

The above works, but only display if the site exists with '301' status code.

**I want**

```
echo $search
https://launchpad.net/~mqchael/+archive/pipelight
```

---

**UPDATE**

This is my new variable, maybe can explain what I need. This variable will allow me to search and install a ppa in Ubuntu o similar.

```
ppa=$(curl https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=$packagename | grep '<td><a href="/~' | grep ">$packagename<" )

echo $ppa
```

**Example:**

`ppa=$(curl https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=Pipelight | grep '<td><a href="/~' | grep ">Pipelight<" )`

```
echo $ppa 

<td><a href="/~mqchael/+archive/pipelight">Pipelight</a></td>
```

The problem here is I can't extract `mqchael` (this name is variable), also pipelight is only a example.

**This is the format final when I will apply my variable.**

```
ppa:mqchael/pipelight
```

Comment: Does the answer specified work? If you need a more specific answer, please let me know :)

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh the idea is display the search found, `https://launchpad.net/~mqchael/+archive/pipelight`, because I will making a patron in ppa with your complete name.

Comment: Cant you just var=$(curl -operands $url_is_last_arg >&2 ; echo ${_##*namefilter=}) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
curl https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=Pipelight |  awk -F/ '/>Pipelight</{print $2}'
```

**Explanation:**

The `-F/` sets the filed delimiter to `/`, and the `/>Pipelight</` means "run the commands in the `{}` only on lines matching `>Pipelight<`. So, at least in the example you posted, the line with `>Pipelight<` is:

```
<td><a href="/~mqchael/+archive/pipelight">Pipelight</a></td>
```

So, since `awk` is splitting on `/`, the first field will be `<td><a href="` and the second will be `~mqchael`. Which is why `{print $2}` will print `~mqchael`.

If you also want to get rid of the tilde (`~`), use this:

```
curl https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=Pipelight |  
    awk -F/ '/>Pipelight</{print $2}' | sed 's/~//'
```

Comment: this is my new variable, maybe can explain what I need. `ppa=$(curl https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=Pipelight | grep '<td><a href="/~' | grep ">Pipelight<" ); echo "ppa=$ppa" > /tmp/lauchpad.txt`
The problem here is I can't extract `~mqchael` is variable this name, pipelight is only a example.

Comment: @davidva see updated answer.

Comment: only a problem, the line `awk -F/ '/>Pipelight</{print $2}'` doesn't read my variable, example: `awk -F/ '/>$my_program</{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to find out the sites which have `301` status code returned. You can actually write the contents of the `curl` command to a file and do a `grep` on **Location** to find out the URLs for the status code `301`. Try this one.

```
curl -s --head -w %{http_code} https://launchpad.net/~[a-z]/+archive/pipelight -o
grep 'Location' file1.txt
```

The output would be,

```
Location: https://launchpad.net/~j/+archive/ppa/pipelight
```

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work, the idea is display  the search found, `https://launchpad.net/~mqchael/+archive/pipelight`, because I will making a patron in ppa with your complete name.

Answer (score 0):

```
code=$desired_HTML_return_code
url="https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=Pipelight"
_curl=$( curl -o /dev/stderr -sL -w \
    "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" "$url" ) 
[ ${_curl%%[!0-9]*} -eq  $code ] && {\
    ppa="${_curl##*~}"
    ppa="ppa:${ppa%%/*}/${_curl##*namefilter=}" 
}
```

So I haven't tested the above, but apparently [this guy](http://beerpla.net/2010/06/10/how-to-display-just-the-http-response-code-in-cli-curl/) has, and he also explains pretty well what the various *`curl`* operands are doing, not to mention many others you have at your disposal. The point is, though, that you use *`curl`* itself to guarantee its output rather than relying on parsers to any great degree.

As written *`curl`* should print to its *`stdout`* only the http return code of its query and the URL you feed it - which doesn't have to be a variable but is above for readability and to demonstrate that it *can* be.

> So the next thing we do is *`${`strip`%%*}`* from the *`%%`tail* of that output as far forward as we **can* until we encounter the first *`[`character`]`* in the string that *`!`isn't* a *`0-9`number.*
>
> Then we *`[`test`]`* the resulting numeric string against our desired http return *`$code.`*
>
> *`&&If`* they *`-equal`* we *`${strip##*}`* from the *`##head`* of our stored *`$_curl`* output as far forward as we can up to and including the last *`~tilde`* it contains and *`assign=`* the results to *`$ppa`.*
>
> Then we *`assign= $ppa`* again to:
>
> > The string "ppa:" plus:
> >
> > *`${ppa's}`* previous value *`${less%%*}`* the first *`/forward-slash`* it contains and everything thereafter plus:
> >
> > Only what remains of *`$_curl`* after *`${removing##*}`* from its *`##head`*  everything up to and including the string *`"namefilter="`*

This offers some advantages over the other solutions.

> As already explained, *`curl`* guarantees its standard output only to be the short string *`"$code $url"`*, but, as written, it also sends the html results to your terminal for debugging on standard error. Its results are *not* consumed by a parsing program.
>
> Only two applications are involved here: *`curl`* and whatever POSIX-compatible shell in which you invoke it.
>
> The results are explicitly tested in the current shell environment and are not consumed on the far side of a subshelled pipe nor are they the result of a regular expression.

It has one disadvantage:

> It depends upon the *`"namefilter=$RESULT"`* being the tail of your URL string. It is possible to handle using the same mechanics applied here if it is not, but it will likely require at least one more shell command. *`sed`* and *`awk`* both offer more powerful string searches than simple *`${parameter##expansion}`* globs ever could.

BUT because we tailor *`curl`'s* output to our purpose in the first place you don't need powerful string searches. So long as your desired http code is returned to *`curl`* AND your output should be *`"namefilter=$desired_string"`* then I don't see how *`$ppa`* can ever equal anything it shouldn't.

If you should accept multiple http return codes your *`[`test`]`* should look like this:

```
codes="$code1 $code2 $code3"
...
[ "${codes#*"${_curl%%[!0-9]*}"} -ne "$codes" ] && ppa=...
```